# Any ideas on creating a GNU radio block for scanning active frequencies (FM/AM/DAB/DVB-T)?

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I am trying to create a GNU Radio block that scans the active frequencies, let's say for FM/DAB channel. I have seen scanner implementations in c++/python but are not compatible with GNU Radio. Can someone guide me on creating a GNU scanner block?

Comment: Is that meant to be FM broadcasts over DAB or a scanner that works both for FM and / or DAB broadcasts?

Comment: It is meant for FM broadcasts

Comment: This is both to broad and sounds more like a general programming than a signal processing question.

Comment: [DAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_broadcasting) and [DVB-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVB-T) is fundamentally different to FM / AM broadcasting. A scanner that scans classic FM / AM receptions is trivial as a [heterodyne tuner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodyne) followed by threshold detection for carriers that are strong enough. This can be implemented in [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/) (if someone has not already done it). The question is too broad indeed. What does the sort of guidance you are after looks like?